# How to check is first character is ñ - Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I get a word from a form, and to slugify it I want to differentiate it.

Using django's slugify if I get the word 'Ñandu', the slug becomes 'nandu'. And if I get the word 'Nandu' the slug also becomes 'nandu'.

So I decided that if the word starts with 'Ñ' the slug will become 'word_ene'.

The problem is I can't find a way to check if the first character from the input is really a 'ñ' (or 'ñ').

I have tried both self.palabra[0]==u"ñ" and self.palabra[0]=="ñ" with and without encoding palabra before. But I can't get to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get when you `print self.palabra[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> str = u"Ñandu"
>>> str[0] == u"\xd1"
True
>>> if str[0] == u"\xd1": print "Begins with \xd1!"
Begins with Ñ!
```

Watch out for case; lower case ñ is encoded as u"\xf1".

Comment: Thanks John! That answers my question, but I had already found a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you type things like u"ñ" directly in the code, then you have to remember about putting sth like (with your coding of choice of course):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

at the top of your .py file, otherwise Python doesn't know what to do.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/